# CFML (ColdFusion 6) access undocumented JAVA class TwoFishCryptor

Tags: java, cfml

I have the following CFML script in which I try to use the ColdFusion JAVA class found in `coldfusion.sql.TwoFishCryptor`:

```
<cfscript>
twofishcryptor = createObject("java","coldfusion.sql.TwoFishCryptor");
newPass = twofishcryptor.encrypt("p455w0rd");
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>Encrypted: #newPass#<br></cfoutput>
```

But I get the following error:
[image]
Below is the full JAVA class code:

```
package coldfusion.sql;

import java.io.PrintStream;

final class TwoFishCryptor
{
  private static final char[] HEX_DIGITS = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
  private static final byte[] HEX_BYTES = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
  private static final byte[] keyArray = { 86, -68, -54, 55, -108, -127, -90, 23, 9, 89, -6, -37, -52, -3, 64, 26 };
  Object key = null;
  int inputSize;

  TwoFishCryptor()
  {
    try
    {
      this.key = TwoFish_Algorithm.makeKey(keyArray);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      try
      {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    this.inputSize = TwoFish_Algorithm.blockSize();
  }

  protected String encrypt(String cleartext)
  {
    byte[] input = cleartext.getBytes();
    byte[] paddedInput = new byte[this.inputSize];

    System.arraycopy(input, 0, paddedInput, 0, input.length > this.inputSize ? this.inputSize : input.length);
    if (input.length < this.inputSize) {
      for (int i = input.length; i < this.inputSize; i++) {
        paddedInput[i] = 0;
      }
    }
    byte[] encryptedBlock = TwoFish_Algorithm.blockEncrypt(paddedInput, 0, this.key);
    return toString(encryptedBlock, 0, encryptedBlock.length);
  }

  protected String decrypt(String encryptedText)
  {
    if ((encryptedText == null) || (encryptedText.length() == 0)) {
      return encryptedText;
    }
    byte[] input = toByte(encryptedText);
    if (input.length > this.inputSize)
    {
      System.out.println("corrupted data...");
      return "";
    }
    byte[] decryptBytes = TwoFish_Algorithm.blockDecrypt(input, 0, this.key);



    int paddingIndex = -1;
    for (int n = 0; n < decryptBytes.length; n++) {
      if (decryptBytes[n] == 0)
      {
        paddingIndex = n;
        break;
      }
    }
    byte[] paddingRemovedBytes;
    String paddingRemovedString;
    if (paddingIndex != -1)
    {
      paddingRemovedBytes = new byte[paddingIndex];
      System.arraycopy(decryptBytes, 0, paddingRemovedBytes, 0, paddingIndex);
      paddingRemovedString = new String(paddingRemovedBytes);
    }
    else
    {
      paddingRemovedBytes = new byte[decryptBytes.length];
      System.arraycopy(decryptBytes, 0, paddingRemovedBytes, 0, decryptBytes.length);
    }
    char[] decryptedChars = new char[paddingRemovedBytes.length];
    for (int m = 0; m < paddingRemovedBytes.length; m++) {
      decryptedChars[m] = ((char)paddingRemovedBytes[m]);
    }
    return new String(decryptedChars);
  }

  private boolean matches(String encryptedText, String clearText)
  {
    String newEncryptedText = encrypt(clearText);
    return encryptedText.equals(newEncryptedText);
  }

  private static boolean areEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
  {
    int aLength = a.length;
    if (aLength != b.length) {
      return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < aLength; i++) {
      if (a[i] != b[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  private static String toString(byte[] ba, int offset, int length)
  {
    char[] buf = new char[length * 2];
    int i = offset;
    for (int j = 0; i < offset + length;)
    {
      int k = ba[(i++)];
      buf[(j++)] = HEX_DIGITS[(k >>> 4 & 0xF)];
      buf[(j++)] = HEX_DIGITS[(k & 0xF)];
    }
    return new String(buf);
  }

  private static byte[] toByte(String encStr)
  {
    char[] buf = encStr.toCharArray();
    byte[] result = new byte[buf.length / 2];
    int resultIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i += 2)
    {
      char ch = buf[i];
      byte firstByte = 0;
      byte secondByte = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < HEX_DIGITS.length; j++) {
        if (ch == HEX_DIGITS[j])
        {
          firstByte = HEX_BYTES[j];
          break;
        }
      }
      ch = buf[(i + 1)];
      for (int k = 0; k < HEX_DIGITS.length; k++) {
        if (ch == HEX_DIGITS[k])
        {
          secondByte = HEX_BYTES[k];
          break;
        }
      }
      byte shiftedFirstByte = (byte)(firstByte << 4 & 0xF0);
      byte shiftedSecondByte = (byte)(secondByte & 0xF);
      byte mergedByte = (byte)(shiftedFirstByte | shiftedSecondByte);
      result[(resultIndex++)] = mergedByte;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to call it from another class.

```
<cfscript>
factory = createObject("java","coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory");
request.sqlexecutive = factory.getDataSourceService();
newPass = request.sqlexecutive.encryptPassword("p455w0rd");
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>Encrypted: #newPass#<br></cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a `protected` method. You can't call it.

Reading: ["Controlling Access to Members of a Class"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: So there no way to call it being `protected`, oops. What about inheritance? Read somewhere that `The only way the subclass can access the protected methods is by inheritance` or using `Reflection API`. Any idea?

Comment: According to those docs if you subclass that class, your subclass can access the protected method. Why not just get a third-party TwoFish implementation, instead of trying to hack into ColdFusion's one?

Comment: Tried that but couldn't find one native to ColdFusion 6, any idea for an easy implementation?

Comment: I mean a *Java* implementation. That said, I'd not be running this sort of thing on CF 6x because it requires Java 1.4, and... that's sooooo out of date it seems a bit contrary to be trying to do security type stuff on it anyhow. How is it you're still on 6?

Comment: Some of my clients still on 6, I'm on 10 waiting for 11 though.

Comment: Are they aware how potentially dangerous that is? It shoudl be good billable work to upgrade them ;-). CF11 will be out in a few months (I reckon mid-end Q2), but - TBH - I would not *touch it* until the first round of patching takes place, which'll probably not be until later in the year. It might be OK to wait, but in your boat I'd go to CF10. Indeed I'd consider going to Railo instead. It'll be a non-insubstantial upgrade from 6->10, so might as well take the plunge to Railo instead.

Comment: They will make the big step to CF11, anyway admin interface is not open to Internet. Railo is a good option also. Needed this undocumented native `TwoFishCryptor` because I can't see any other way out-of-the-box with CF6, I hate it...